# Como poder tener los datos en una relacion muchos a muchos la relacion de la tabla central?

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js

tengo una relacion muchos a muchos utilizando sequelize con node.js el problema es que en la tabla central tengo una relacion extra y quiero que tambien me muestre la informacion de esa relacion los modelos son los siguientes:

Order.model.js
aqui es donde tengo items que es de tipo belongsTo de sequelize solo que no se como hacer lo anterior descrito.

```
const { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const { CUSTOMER_TABLE } = require('./customer.model');
const { ADDRESS_TABLE } = require('./address.model');
const { TECNICO_TABLE } = require('./tecnico.model');
const { PAYMENT_TABLE } = require('./payment.model');

const ORDER_TABLE = 'orders';

const OrderSchema = {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  customerId: {
    field: 'customer_id',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: CUSTOMER_TABLE,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  },
  tecnicoId: {
    field: 'tecnico_id',
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: TECNICO_TABLE,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  },
  addressId: {
    field: 'address_id',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: ADDRESS_TABLE,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  },
  status: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    defaultValue: 'procesando',
  },
  date: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    defaultValue: null,
  },

  paymentId: {
    field: 'payment_id',
    type: Sequelize.DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: PAYMENT_TABLE,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    field: 'created_at',
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  },
  total: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get() {
      if (this.items && this.items.length > 0) {
        return this.items.reduce((total, item) => {
          console.log(item.OrderProduct);
          return total + this.payment.price * item.OrderProduct.amount;
        }, 0);
      }
      return 0;
    },
  },
};

class Order extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Customer, {
      as: 'customer',
      foreignKey: 'customerId',
    });
    this.belongsTo(models.Payment, {
      as: 'payment',
      foreignKey: 'paymentId',
    });
    this.belongsTo(models.Address, { as: 'address', foreignKey: 'addressId' });
    this.belongsTo(models.Tecnico, { as: 'tecnico', foreignKey: 'tecnicoId' });
    this.belongsToMany(models.Product, {
      through: models.OrderProduct,
      foreignKey: 'orderId',
      otherKey: 'productId',
      as: 'items',
      association:'priceProduct'
    });
  }

  static config(sequelize) {
    return {
      sequelize,
      tableName: ORDER_TABLE,
      modelName: 'Order',
      timestamps: false,
    };
  }
}

module.exports = { Order, OrderSchema, ORDER_TABLE };
```

Product.model.js

```
const { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const { CATEGORY_TABLE } = require('./category.model');
const { PRICE_TABLE } = require('./price.model');
const PRODUCT_TABLE = 'products';

const ProductSchema = {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  image: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  priceId: {
    field: 'price_id',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: PRICE_TABLE,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    field: 'created_at',
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  },
  active: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    defaultValue: 'true',
  },
  categoryId: {
    field: 'category_id',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: CATEGORY_TABLE,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  },
};




class Product extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Category, { as: 'category' });
    this.belongsTo(models.Price, {
      as: 'prices',
      foreignKey: 'priceId',
    });
    this.hasMany(models.OrderProduct, {
      as:'orderProduct',
      foreignKey: 'productId'
    })
    this.belongsToMany(models.Order, {
      through: models.OrderProduct,
      foreignKey: 'orderId',
      otherKey: 'productId',
    });

  }

  static config(sequelize) {
    return {
      sequelize,
      tableName: PRODUCT_TABLE,
      modelName: 'Product',
      timestamps: false,
    };
  }
}

module.exports = { Product, ProductSchema, PRODUCT_TABLE };
```

order-product.model.js

```
const { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const { ORDER_TABLE } = require('./order.model');
const { PRODUCT_TABLE } = require('./product.model');
const { PRICE_TABLE } = require('./price.model');
const ORDER_PRODUCT_TABLE = 'orders_products';

const OrderProductSchema = {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    field: 'created_at',
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  },
  amount: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  orderId: {
    field: 'order_id',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: ORDER_TABLE,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  },
  productId: {
    field: 'product_id',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: PRODUCT_TABLE,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  },
  priceId: {
    field: 'price_id',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: PRICE_TABLE,
      key: 'id',
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
  },
};
class OrderProduct extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Price, {
      as: 'priceProduct',
      foreignKey: 'priceId',
    });
    this.belongsTo(models.Product,{
      as:'product',
      foreignKey:'productId'
    })
  }

  static config(sequelize) {
    return {
      sequelize,
      tableName: ORDER_PRODUCT_TABLE,
      modelName: 'OrderProduct',
      timestamps: false,
    };
  }
}

module.exports = { OrderProduct, OrderProductSchema, ORDER_PRODUCT_TABLE };
```

price.model.js

```
const { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const PRICE_TABLE = 'prices';

const PriceSchema = {
  id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  price: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    field: 'created_at',
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  },
};

class Price extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.hasMany(models.Product, {
      as: 'prices',
      foreignKey: 'priceId',
    });
    this.hasMany(models.OrderProduct, {
      as: 'OPprices',
      foreignKey: 'priceId',
    });
  }

  static config(sequelize) {
    return {
      sequelize,
      tableName: PRICE_TABLE,
      modelName: 'Price',
      timestamps: false,
    };
  }
}

module.exports = { Price, PRICE_TABLE, PriceSchema };
```

la consulta que quiero hacer es la siguiente :

```
  async findByUser(data) {
    const orders = await models.Order.findAll({
      offset: data.offset,
      limit: data.limit,
      where: {
        customerId: data.id,
      },
      include: [
        {
          association: 'address',
          attributes: {
            exclude: ['createdAt', 'customerId'],
          },
        },
        {
          association: 'tecnico',
        },
        {
          association: 'items',
          // include: [
          //   {
          //     association: 'orderProduct',
            
          //     include: [
          //       {
          //         association: 'priceProduct',
                  
          //       },
          //     ],
          //   },
          // ],
        },
        {
          association: 'payment',
          attributes: {
            exclude: ['paymentIntentId', 'checkoutSessionId', 'id'],
          },
        },
      ],
      order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    });

    const count = await models.Order.count({
      where: {
        customerId: data.id,
      },
    });

    return {
      rows: orders,
      count: count,
    };
  }
```

y me da una respuesta como la siguiente:

```
{
    "total": null,
    "id": 6,
    "customerId": 1,
    "tecnicoId": null,
    "addressId": 1,
    "status": "procesando",
    "date": null,
    "paymentId": 2,
    "createdAt": "2023-07-24T15:20:59.459Z",
    "address": {
        "addressId": 1,
        "name": "name",
        "lastName": "lastname",
        "cp": "21458",
        "state": "estado",
        "city": "ciudad",
        "colonia": "colonia",
        "street": "calles  ",
        "externalNumber": "545",
        "internalNumber": null,
        "street1": null,
        "street2": null,
        "phone": "541651651651",
        "aditionalIndications": "casa roja de dos pisos "
    },
    "tecnico": null,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "instalar camaras de seguridad",
            "image": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dxluzrikm/image/upload/q_auto:low/v1689617079/m9tqxqrzvurkeseuqujt.jpg",
            "description": "instalar camaras",
            "priceId": 7,
            "createdAt": "2023-07-17T18:04:38.122Z",
            "active": "true",
            "categoryId": 1,
            "OrderProduct": {
                "id": 2,
                "createdAt": "2023-07-24T15:20:59.507Z",
                "amount": 2,
                "orderId": 6,
                "productId": 1,
                "priceId": 6
            }
        }
    ],
    "payment": {
        "paymentStatus": "paid",
        "checkoutStatus": "complete",
        "link": "https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1lcu8lWNYYUe2DDVpSOghiI3EDK0PoYiaBJccSVLmM9t0eKwMcuBLowet#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjA0SHxnc0BBfW91dWpQfDBPc29hQnNMd2BnfFRfQzJfd1MzNU89XFRLTHRxUDZnZEFDanV0ZGM0TmprRF80ak5TZz1XfG02cmNoT0p%2Fb0ZfdF9TYF00d3Y2NTVOfzVNM2tkcScpJ2N3amhWYHdzYHcnP3F3cGApJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPyd2bGtiaWBabHFgaCcpJ2BrZGdpYFVpZGZgbWppYWB3dic%2FcXdwYHgl"
    }
}
```

y quiero que donde dice "OrderProduct" tambien me tariga la relacion de price.model.js